# jQuery OO Event-binding

Tags: javascript-objects, jquery

Basically, I've an object:

```
function tomatoe(name, owner) {
    $('<div>').click(this.squish).appendTo(myElement).text('I\'m a happy tomatoe called ' + name);

    this.name = name;
    this.dead = false;
    this.owner = owner;
    this.squish = function() {
        console.log('Oh my Google, you killed ' + this.name + '!');
        this.dead = true;
        this.owner.sad = true;
    };
}
```

The functionality is pretty straightforward. When instantiated, create a div, attach a click handler to it, and staple it onto something. Upon instantiation, two parameters are passed: a name and an owner. The owner is a reference to another object.

There are two problems with this code:

1. The this reference in the squish function is broken, since it now refers to the element clicked.
2. Because of chaining, when actually attaching the event, "this" refers to either jQuery or the newly-created div element (not sure which yet), so this.squish is undefined and never called.

If it helps in any way, the owner object has a reference to all tomatoes.

Comment: *facepalm* I'm such an idiot...creating another instance of yourself is in OO JavaScript 101

Comment: All your answers are correct...gonna let a random number generator decide which one.

Comment: lol @Zirak usually its the 1st correct one that gets the cake :-p

Comment: I think I took random number generation a bit too far: http://jsfiddle.net/RJEyu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to reassigned `this` to another variable so that the naming doesn't collide. It is also a good idea to create the div after you instantiated all of the variables.

```
function tomatoe(name, owner) {
    var that = this;

    that.name = name;
    that.dead = false;
    that.owner = owner;
    that.squish = function() {
        console.log('Oh my Google, you killed ' + that.name + '!');
        that.dead = true;
        that.owner.sad = true;
    };

    $('<div>').click(that.squish).appendTo(myElement).text('I\'m a happy tomatoe called ' + name);

}
```

Comment: You win the random number generator extreme. Thanks and congrats

Comment: @Zirak, you realize that is not how you are really supposed to pick answers on stack

Comment: @Neal When multiple answers appear within a short period of time (like a minute or so), all answers are considered genuine. The OP may choose any of those answers. It would be different if this answer was posted like 10 minutes after another equally valid answer, but that is not the case here.

Comment: @Sime ok, i was looking it up on the meta, and it is vague over there

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function tomatoe(name, owner) {

    //make a reference to this with self
    var self = this;

    $('<div>').click(self.squish).appendTo(myElement).text('I\'m a happy tomatoe called ' + name);

    this.name = name;
    this.dead = false;
    this.owner = owner;
    this.squish = function() {
        console.log('Oh my Google, you killed ' + this.name + '!');
        this.dead = true;
        this.owner.sad = true;
    };
}
```

what i would do if you want chanability:

```
var tomato = {
     name: null,
     dead: null,
     owner: null,

     init: function(name, owner){
          var self = this;
          $('<div>').click(self.squish)
                .appendTo(myElement).text('I\'m a happy tomatoe called ' + name);
          this.name = name;
          this.dead = false;
          this.owner = owner;
          return this;
     },

     squish: function(){
          console.log('Oh my Google, you killed ' + this.name + '!');
          this.dead = true;
          this.owner.sad = true;
          return this;
     }

}

//to instantiate it:
tomato.init(name, owner);
```

Comment: Sime, i beleieve this still refers to the  correct this in the nested fn, i could be wrong though

Comment: @Neal Yes, you're right. However, the jQuery line has to appear below the `this.squish` assignment. You don't need to create the `self` variable at all - inside `click()` `this` still refers to the instance.

Comment: @Sime, that is possible, but not the same in my json solution

Comment: @Neal No wait, you're not right `:)`. The function is used as a click handler. Therefore, `this` refers to the element that is clicked (the DIV), and not the instance object.

Comment: @Neal I am referring to your first code-block. When the jQuery line executes, `self.squish` is undefined because no value has been assigned to it yet.

Comment: @sime, how are you supposed to choose the best answer? idk if random number gen is the best way

Answer (score 1):

You have to place the jQuery line **after** the `this.squish` assignment! It is obviously undefined, until you assign a value to it.

```
function tomatoe(name, owner) {  

    var that = this;

    this.name = name;
    this.dead = false;
    this.owner = owner;
    this.squish = function() {
        console.log('Oh my Google, you killed ' + that.name + '!');
        that.dead = true;
        that.owner.sad = true;
    };

    $('<div>').click(this.squish).appendTo(myElement)
              .text('I\'m a happy tomatoe called ' + name);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the easiest way of doing what you want to do is to create a local variable to store a reference to the tomatoe object like so:

```
function tomatoe(name, owner) {
  var _this = this;
  $('<div>').click(this.squish).appendTo(myElement).text('I\'m a happy tomatoe called ' + name);

  this.name = name;
  this.dead = false;
  this.owner = owner;
  this.squish = function() {
    console.log('Oh my Google, you killed ' + _this.name + '!');
    _this.dead = true;
    _this.owner.sad = true;
  };
}
```